# Formatting integers with a decimal place in sql query

Tags: sql, formatting, numbers

I had the table, resulted from a query as follow:

```
Lasiorhinus 100
Macrotis    100
Myrmecobius 100
Panthera    50
Sarcophilus 100
```

The query is sth like this:

```
select round (count(A) / count(B), 1)
```

But I'd like the numbers to be formatted as follow:

```
Lasiorhinus 100.0
Macrotis    100.0
Myrmecobius 100.0
Panthera    50.0
Sarcophilus 100.0
```

Could anyone help me to format the integer 50 => 50.0 with ROUND(number, 1) function? thank you.

Comment: depends on RDBMS but I assume you mean SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks Mitch. I am using SQL developer.

Comment: Could you give me some examples of RDBMS? I am new to this subject.

Comment: RDBMS stands for Relational DataBase Management System.  It's also known as a database engine or database software.  Examples are sql server, oracle, mysql, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (SQL Server)  would be:

```
select format(round(count(A) / count(B), 1), 'N1')
```

Ref.:

- [Round()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)
- [Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh213505.aspx)

Comment: My query is like this. I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work.
SELECT spec_genus, 
       ROUND((SELECT COUNT(animal_id) 
             FROM as2.ANIMAL 
             WHERE brevent_id IS NULL AND spec_genus = a.spec_genus 
             GROUP BY spec_genus) / COUNT(animal_id),1) AS PERCENTAGE
                                    FROM as2.ANIMAL a
                                    GROUP BY spec_genus
                                    ORDER BY spec_genus;

Comment: what does 'doesn't work' mean? I tried this and it works!